# is there a solution for flutter Icons not showing properly?

Tags: flutter

I hope you are doing well. I'm studying flutter and got into this issue while developing the navbar for the app, the icons were not showing properly.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R3o0.png)

i tried clearing the cash and updating flutter and dart packages ,but it didn't work

Comment: did you try this command for clean ? flutter pub cache clean

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your code. My first guess is that you are using emojis, not icons. Am I correct? And you then are simply using a font that doesn't support those.

Comment: Please add your pubspec.yaml file and also where you added the icons and how you load them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've enabled material design and if you are using Cupertino icon, also include on pubspec.yaml

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 #use latest

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```